# MS SQL 2000 - Parameters in DTSRUN using xp_cmdshell

Tags: sql-server, xp-cmdshell

I am running the following:
master..xp_cmdshell 'dtsrun /S ricmssql02 /U admindw /P letmein /N "scott - debug"'
but also send parameters.  I am seeing the following to do that:
/A global_parameter_name:typeid=value
And also that the whole thing can be repeated to send multiple.
My questions are; What is the delimiter for multiple? What are the values for typeid or do I even need it?

Answer (score 1):

Although DTSRUN will usually work without it, the values for typeid are as follows:

```
Data type Type ID
-----------------
Integer (small) 2
Integer 3
Real (4-byte) 4
Real (8-byte) 5
Currency 6
Date 7
String 8
Boolean 11
Decimal 14
Integer (1-byte) 16
Unsigned int (1-byte) 17
Unsigned int (2-byte) 18
Unsigned int (4-byte) 19
Integer (8-byte) 20
Unsigned int (8-byte) 21
Int 22
Unsigned int 23
HRESULT 25
Pointer 26
LPSTR 30
LPWSTR 31
```

I'm not sure what you mean by "delimiter for multiple" - you need to have an /A for each variable you want to replace. So, if you wanted to set three string variables in your example:

```
master..xp_cmdshell 'dtsrun /S ricmssql02 /U admindw /P letmein /N "scott - debug" /A "param1:8=string 1" /A "param2:8=string 2" /A "param3:8=string 3"'
```